Apex - Variable does not exist: objLead (line:72)
I'm not a developer, and I am trying to modify this class to include a Lead field Agent_Referral__c in each Opportunity created. However, the Salesforce validation says I don't have the variable objLead set correctly.
What syntax am I missing here, please?
// This class used in 'Lead Converted flow' flow and also use to send product's values list to leadConversionMultiselectPicklist lwc component.
public with sharing class CreateOpportunityRecordsUsingProductList {
    
    public static List<List<String>> listToReturnOpportunityId = new List<List<String>>();

    // This method use to return the inserted opportunity list
    @InvocableMethod(label='Return newly inserted opportunity list to flow')
    public static List<List<String>> returnOpportunityFromProductNames() {
        System.debug('inside invocable: '+listToReturnOpportunityId);
        return listToReturnOpportunityId;
    }
    
    // This method use to send the list of product picklist values in lwc component - leadConversionMultiselectPicklist
    @AuraEnabled
    public static List<String> getProductListValues(String recordId) {
        
        System.debug('recordId: '+recordId);
        
        List<string> listProductString= new List<String>();
        
        Lead objLead= [SELECT Id, Product_Interested__c,agent_referral__c  FROM Lead WHERE Id=: recordId WITH SECURITY_ENFORCED];
        
        if(objLead.Product_Interested__c!= NULL) {
            
            String productString= objLead.Product_Interested__c;
            
            System.debug(productString);
            
            listProductString= productString.split(';');
            
            System.debug(listProductString);
        }
        return listProductString;
    }      
    
    // This method use to create opportunities from listProductName
    @AuraEnabled
    public static void createOpportunityFromProductNames(List<String> listProductName, String accountId, String contactId, String recordId) {
        
        System.debug('listProductName : '+listProductName);
        System.debug('leadId::'+recordId);
        System.debug('accountId : '+accountId);
        System.debug('contactId : '+contactId);
        
        String productNameString='';
        
        List<String> listOpportunityId = new List<String>();
        List<Opportunity> listOpportunity = new List<Opportunity>();
        
        Account objAccount = [SELECT Id, Name, CurrencyIsoCode FROM Account WHERE Id = :accountId WITH SECURITY_ENFORCED LIMIT 1 ];
        
        if(listProductName.size()> 0 && objAccount.Name!=null) {
            
            for (String productName : listProductName) {
                Opportunity v1 = new Opportunity(
                    Name = objAccount.Name + ' - ' + productName,       
                    CloseDate = Date.today().addDays(14), 
                    StageName = 'Qualification',                    
                    AccountId = objAccount.Id,
                    CurrencyIsoCode= objAccount.CurrencyIsoCode,
                    Product_Interested__c=productName,
                    Agent_Referral__c=objLead.Agent_Referral__c
                                );
                Opportunity opp = v1;
                listOpportunity.add(opp);
            }
            
            if (listOpportunity.size() > 0) {
                if (Schema.sObjectType.Opportunity.isCreateable()){
                     insert listOpportunity;
                } 
            }
            
            for (Opportunity objOpportunity : listOpportunity) {
                listOpportunityId.add(objOpportunity.Id);
            }
            
            listToReturnOpportunityId.add(listOpportunityId);
        }
        
        if(listOpportunityId.size()>= 2) {
            for(Id OppId: listOpportunityId) {
                if(productNameString== Null) {
                    productNameString= OppId;
                }
                else {
                    productNameString= productNameString+ '   '+ OppId;
                }
            }
        }
        
        Lead objLead= [SELECT Id, Lead_Converted_Opportunity_Id__c FROM Lead WHERE Id=: recordId WITH SECURITY_ENFORCED LIMIT 1];
        
        // Updating Lead_Converted_Opportunity_Id__c custom field of lead 
        if(productNameString!= NULL){
            objLead.Lead_Converted_Opportunity_Id__c= productNameString;
        }  
        
        if (Schema.sObjectType.Lead.isUpdateable()){
            update ObjLead;     
        }
        
        
        // Updating ConvertedAccountId, ConvertedContactId, isConverted standard fields of lead using Database.LeadConvert's instance
        Database.LeadConvert lc = new Database.LeadConvert();
        
        lc.setDoNotCreateOpportunity(True);
        //lc.isDoNotCreateOpportunity();
        
        lc.setLeadId(objLead.Id);
        
        if(accountId!= NULL) {
            lc.setAccountId(accountId);
        }
        if(contactId!= NULL) {
            lc.setContactId(contactId);
        }
        
        LeadStatus convertStatus = [SELECT Id, MasterLabel FROM LeadStatus WHERE IsConverted = TRUE WITH SECURITY_ENFORCED LIMIT 1];
        lc.setConvertedStatus(convertStatus.MasterLabel);
        
        Database.LeadConvertResult lcr = Database.convertLead(lc);
        System.debug('lcr: '+lcr);
        
        System.debug('listToReturnOpportunityId : '+listToReturnOpportunityId);
    }
}


You must declare a variable before using it. In createOpportunityFromProductNames you used objlead here
Agent_Referral__c=objLead.Agent_Referral__c

But you declared it only several line after that:
Lead objLead= [SELECT Id, Lead_Converted_Opportunity_Id__c FROM Lead WHERE Id=: recordId WITH SECURITY_ENFORCED LIMIT 1];

You should move that line right after Account objAccount = ....
Moreover you should query every field you want to read, otherwise you'll get an exception, so since you need Agent_Referral__c you must add it to the query.
Please also note that an empty string, like productNameString='', is not null, so productNameString== Null will always be false. To check whether a string is empty or null, you could leverage String.isBlank().
That's the updated method:
@AuraEnabled
public static void createOpportunityFromProductNames(List<String> listProductName, String accountId, String contactId, String recordId) {
    
    System.debug('listProductName : '+listProductName);
    System.debug('leadId::'+recordId);
    System.debug('accountId : '+accountId);
    System.debug('contactId : '+contactId);
    
    String productNameString='';
    
    List<String> listOpportunityId = new List<String>();
    List<Opportunity> listOpportunity = new List<Opportunity>();
    
    Account objAccount = [SELECT Id, Name, CurrencyIsoCode FROM Account WHERE Id = :accountId WITH SECURITY_ENFORCED LIMIT 1];
    
    Lead objLead = [SELECT Agent_Referral__c, Lead_Converted_Opportunity_Id__c FROM Lead WHERE Id = :recordId WITH SECURITY_ENFORCED LIMIT 1];
    
    if(listProductName.size()> 0 && objAccount.Name!=null) {
        
        for (String productName : listProductName) {
            Opportunity opp = new Opportunity(
                Name = objAccount.Name + ' - ' + productName,       
                CloseDate = Date.today().addDays(14), 
                StageName = 'Qualification',                    
                AccountId = objAccount.Id,
                CurrencyIsoCode= objAccount.CurrencyIsoCode,
                Product_Interested__c=productName,
                Agent_Referral__c=objLead.Agent_Referral__c
            );
            listOpportunity.add(opp);
        }
        
        if (listOpportunity.size() > 0 && Schema.sObjectType.Opportunity.isCreateable()) {
            insert listOpportunity;
        }
        
        for (Opportunity objOpportunity : listOpportunity) {
            listOpportunityId.add(objOpportunity.Id);
        }
        
        listToReturnOpportunityId.add(listOpportunityId);
    }
    
    if(listOpportunityId.size()>= 2) {
        for(Id OppId: listOpportunityId) {
            if(String.isBlank(productNameString)) {
                productNameString = OppId;
            }
            else {
                productNameString = productNameString + '   ' + OppId;
            }
        }
    }
    
    // Updating Lead_Converted_Opportunity_Id__c custom field of lead 
    if(String.isNotBlank(productNameString)){
        objLead.Lead_Converted_Opportunity_Id__c= productNameString;
    }  
    
    if (Schema.sObjectType.Lead.isUpdateable()){
        update ObjLead;     
    }
    
    
    // Updating ConvertedAccountId, ConvertedContactId, isConverted standard fields of lead using Database.LeadConvert's instance
    Database.LeadConvert lc = new Database.LeadConvert();
    
    lc.setDoNotCreateOpportunity(True);
    //lc.isDoNotCreateOpportunity();
    
    lc.setLeadId(objLead.Id);
    
    if (String.isNotBlank(accountId)) {
        lc.setAccountId(accountId);
    }
    if (String.isNotBlank(contactId)) {
        lc.setContactId(contactId);
    }
    
    LeadStatus convertStatus = [SELECT Id, MasterLabel FROM LeadStatus WHERE IsConverted = TRUE WITH SECURITY_ENFORCED LIMIT 1];
    lc.setConvertedStatus(convertStatus.MasterLabel);
    
    Database.LeadConvertResult lcr = Database.convertLead(lc);
    System.debug('lcr: '+lcr);
    
    System.debug('listToReturnOpportunityId : '+listToReturnOpportunityId);
}

Beware: in that method you are also using listToReturnOpportunityId which is a static variable of that class, but keep in mind that, unlike other languages like Java, Apex static variables are bound to a single transaction and each time a LWC calls an Apex method a new transaction is started, so you cannot use listToReturnOpportunityId to store a state of your application, ergo returnOpportunityFromProductNames will return an empty list.

Thanks for the solution and the additional comments to improve the code.
